# Checking status of layer calculation using API

Tags: python, carto

I wrote a python script that updates the values in a dataset and then returns a static image of the map it's connected to.

The problem is if I download the image too soon after updating the dataset, one of the visualization layers on the map that requires a lot of calculations won't show up.

I don't want to have to set a manual wait time in the code because the size of the data I'm uploading could range from 100 to 10,000 data points.

**Is there an API url I could call that would know when a layer is being updated and when it has finished?**

I have tried using vizualization url but could not find anything in the JSON data about an update status.

```
img_url1 = 'https://%s.carto.com/api/v2/viz/%s/viz.json/?api_key=%s&' %(self.options['u'], map_id, self.options['k'])
r1 = requests.get(img_url1)
print(json.dumps(r4.json(), indent=2))
```

On a similar thread someone sugested using this to refresh the the_geom data but I had no luck there either:

```
refresh_url = "https://{username}.carto.com/api/v2/sql?q=UPDATE table SET the_geom = cdb_latlng(latitude, longitude)&api_key={api_key}".format(username=self.options['u'], api_key=self.options['k'])
r4 = requests.get(refresh_url)
print(json.dumps(r4.json(), indent=2))
```

I have tried using the named map API but the 'Last Updated' field shows the time when the update started not finished, and the 'Date' field just shows the current time.

```
img_url2 = 'https://{user}.carto.com/api/v1/map/named/{template}/jsonp?auth_token={auth_token}&callback=callback'.format(user=self.options['u'], template=tpl_name, auth_token=self.options['k'])
r2 = requests.get(img_url2)
print(r2.headers)


'Date': 'Mon, 10 Feb 2020 20:27:14 GMT', 
'Content-Type': 'text/javascript; charset=utf-8', 
'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 
'Connection': 'keep-alive', 
'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding, Authorization', 
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 
'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'X-Requested-With, X-Prototype-Version, X-CSRF-Token, Authorization', 
'Carto-Rate-Limit-Limit': '21', 
'Carto-Rate-Limit-Remaining': '20', 
'Carto-Rate-Limit-Reset': '0', 
'Cache-Control': 'public,max-age=5,must-revalidate', 
'Surrogate-Key': '{removed for privacy}', 
'Last-Modified': 'Mon, 10 Feb 2020 20:14:40 GMT', 
'X-Layergroup-Id': '{removed for privacy}', 
'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 
'X-Varnish': '47747576', 
'Age': '0', 
'X-Cache': 'MISS', 
'Content-Encoding': 'gzip'
```

Answer (score 0):

From the postgresql side there are system tables that tell you if a query is running but these are not queryable via the Carto API for obvious security reasons.

You could try seeing if the batch API provides the query status see: https://carto.com/developers/sql-api/guides/batch-queries/